# How can i change default language to tamil language in Android Emulator

Tags: android

I want know how to install the tamil language in android emulator., can any one suggest me to type tamil in android amulator

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same as with normal android phone. Settings -> Locale

Comment: is he is able to install new locale in emulator?